# Benoni Defence Theory and Ideas

Tags: theory, modern-benoni

I have played the Benoni for a while, and I frequently play bad moves in the opening. How could I play the Benoni - Pawn Storm Variation safely?

Comment: What's the "pawn storm variation"?

Comment: Where White play e2-e4 and f2-f4.

Comment: I don't think it's very helpful to try and play the Benoni of all openings in a safe manner. It's an inherenly risky opening that will lead black to very bad positions if played without a willingness to play risky chess.

Comment: the Modern Benoni "is definitely not an opening for cowards." - GM Lev Psakhis

Comment: Not answering because I have no idea about the Benoni but pawn pushes tend to be bad because they weaken all squares behind them. There is a nice outpost on d4 eventually and your dark bishop has great potential. Also many have mentioned this but this variation looks to be about unbalances(like the KID or Sicilian) so if you want safe play, this isn't the best opening for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't give a fig about "variations". Players don't lose games in the opening because they're bad at this variation or that system, they lose short games because they're bad at tactics (and that's your experience, yeah?).

Forget the dumb names of things. Pawn Storm This, Big Attack That. You have to learn enough tactics first.